how to achieve a wing style curved shape for image as per the attached screenshot
enter image description here
how to achieve a wing style curved shape for image as per the attached screenshot  using css
Tried with css border radius and alos with clip path css generator we were not able to achieve as per required curve shape for image

clip-path, SVG, mask... please show the code of clip-path that have not worked for you.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You can cut the curve with clip-path: ellipse() and then add the rounded corners at the right side by applying the border-radius only to those corners:


img { 
  display: block;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 120% at 100% 0%);
}
<img src="https://placehold.co/578x559">



